# Power Bi DAX - Calculating Workingdays from a past period

Tags: powerbi, dax

I´m really struggling about the following problem, searched a lot, tried a lot but still I´m not able to achieve my goal. I really hope, that someone can help me out with this.

Situation
I´ve created a meassure:

```
Measure = 
VAR selYear = SELECTEDVALUE('Stats Param LindyCalendar'[Date].[Year])
VAR selMonth = SELECTEDVALUE('Stats Param LindyCalendar'[Month])
VAR selDay = day(now())
VAR enddate = DATE(selYear, selMonth, selDay)
VAR CurWorkingDay = 
    COUNTROWS(
        FILTER(
            FILTER('Stats Param LindyCalendar', 'Stats Param LindyCalendar'[Date].[Date] <= enddate),
             'Stats Param LindyCalendar'[WorkingDay_YN] = -1))
RETURN CurWorkingDay
```

There are three slicers. The first one is based on Country-Table which has correct working relationships to all needed tables. It just filters the Country.
The second slicer is based on 'Stats Param LindyCalendar'[Date].[Year].
The last one is based on 'Stats Param LindyCalendar'[Date].[Month].

When I play around with the slicer, setting random values, it works fine.

Goal:
I want to get back the CurWorkingDay of the last year.
So I did:

```
VAR selYear = SELECTEDVALUE('Stats Param LindyCalendar'[Date].[Year])-1
```

The result is "Blank" in the Card-Visual.

That´s my problem, and I don´t know how to fix that.
Would be great if someone could provide a solution or hint.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: There is a DAX function like SAMEPERIODLASTYEAR. Did you tried that? You can check- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/sameperiodlastyear-function-dax

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got it.

```
    workingdays_MTD = 
VAR selYear = SELECTEDVALUE('Stats Param LindyCalendar'[Date].[Year])-1
VAR selMonth = SELECTEDVALUE('Stats Param LindyCalendar'[Month])
VAR selDay = day(now())
VAR enddate = DATE(selYear, selMonth, selDay)
VAR test = 
    TOTALMTD(COUNTROWS('Stats Param LindyCalendar'),'Stats Param LindyCalendar'[Date].[Date] = enddate,'Stats Param LindyCalendar'[WorkingDay_YN] =-1)
RETURN test
```

Power BI marks an error for "'Stats Param LindyCalendar'[Date].[Date] = enddate," but it works anyway...